# copy data from one sheet to another on the next empty row

Tags: excel, vba

Hy Experts, I am using two excel sheets. One is input and second is Database. In the input sheet, I want to copy the entire data once I click the button on the database sheet. The macro that I am using works good. but instead of pasting the data on the next empty row it start over write the existing data. that is toataly wrong concept. I am using this macro.

```
Sub copydate()
'
' copydate Macro
'

'
    Range("E1:J1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("DATABASE").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Range("A2:A75").Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Sheets("INPUT SHEET").Select
    Range("A3:J77").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("DATABASE").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I am using these sheets. 
[image: Input Sheet]

[image: Database Screen.]

How can i get fiexed this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To help you with this, I’ll need to make the following assumptions:

1 You clear the data in the INPUT SHEET each time prior to adding new data to copy

2 You want to copy the entire range from columns A through J from the INPUT SHEET (your existing code seems to indicate this)

3 I’m assuming you want the date from cell E1 in the INPUT SHEET to be copied to column A next to all new data pasted into the DATABASE sheet
Try the code out with your existing data – if it doesn’t work then adjust the code to suit as best you can.  The only way to learn is to try, try again…

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToDatabase()
Dim LastInput As Long, PasteRow As Long, LastRow As Long

'Find the last row of data to copy
LastInput = Sheets("INPUT SHEET").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row

'Find the row to paste the new data to
If Sheets("DATABASE").Range("A2") <> "" Then
    PasteRow = Sheets("DATABASE").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    Else
    PasteRow = 2
End If

'Copy the data
Sheets("INPUT SHEET").Range("A3:J" & LastInput).Copy _
Sheets("DATABASE").Range("B" & PasteRow)

'Find the last row of newly copied data
LastRow = Sheets("DATABASE").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row

'Put the date next to the newly copied data
Sheets("DATABASE").Range("A" & PasteRow & ":A" & LastRow).Value _
= Sheets("INPUT SHEET").Range("E1").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: bro I am getting error "Object did not support this property type" Error Code "Run Time Error 438"

Comment: Which line of code is causing the problem?  Use the F8 key to step through the code until you find it.